# Google Test: Tests arranges per INSTANTIATE rather than test_fixture

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a question regarding the parameterized tests from the Google test framework.
What I have is a class under test, what I want to test with this specific class is:

1. A range of valid values
2. A range of valid values.
3. A range of invalid value types.

The input for my class is string, which is internally converted to an int.

Now the structure that I came up with in google test is the one pictured below:

```cpp
// Class under test
class MyClass
{
    // Class contents
public:
    void MyFunction(std::string input) 
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
};

class MyClassBaseTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::string>
{};
// In bound values
class MyClassOKTest : public MyClassBaseTest 
{};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(OKValues,
                         MyClassOKTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            "1", "2", "3"
                         ));

TEST_P(MyClassOKTest, OKValuesTest)
{
    MyClass sut;
}

// Out of bound values
class MyClassOutOfBoundTest : public MyClassBaseTest 
{};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(OutOfBound,
                         MyClassOutOfBoundTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            "30", "40", "50"
                         ));

TEST_P(MyClassOutOfBoundTest, OutOfBoundValuesTest)
{
    MyClass sut;
}

// Invalid values values
class MyClassInvalidTest : public MyClassBaseTest 
{};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Invalid,
                         MyClassInvalidTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            "3.0", "Foo", "Bar"
                         ));

TEST_P(MyClassInvalidTest, InvalidValuesTest)
{
    MyClass sut;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is something like below, where I do not have to redefine my test_fixture all over again.

```cpp
// Class under test
class MyClass
{
    // Class contents
public:
    void MyFunction(std::string input) 
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
};

// In bound values
class MyClassTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<ParamType>
{};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(OKValues,
                         MyClassOKTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            "1", "2", "3"
                         ));

TEST_P(OKValues, OKValuesTest)
{
    MyClass sut;
}

// Out of bound values
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(OutOfBound,
                         MyClassOutOfBoundTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            "30", "40", "50"
                         ));

TEST_P(OutOfBound, OutOfBoundValuesTest)
{
    MyClass sut;
}

// Invalid values values
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Invalid,
                         MyClassInvalidTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            "3.0", "Foo", "Bar"
                         ));

TEST_P(Invalid, InvalidValuesTest)
{
    MyClass sut;
}
```

I checked the documentation and it looks like Google Test does not facilitate a structure like this. My question is if my initial setup is the only way to do this, or am I missing something here?

Or if someone has a suggestion on another clean way to structure this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to associate a specific `TEST_P` of a single test suite with a specific `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P`. The `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P` instantiates always all `TEST_P` of the test suite (as the name `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P` already implies). However, you can often move the expectation out of the `TEST_P` tests and into the instantiation, like so ([live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Gn6K6EEhx)):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::optional<int> MyFunction(std::string input) 
    {
        try {
            std::size_t numProcessed = 0;
            int const result = std::stoi(input, &numProcessed);
            if (numProcessed != input.size()) {
                return std::nullopt;
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument const &){
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
};

struct Params
{
    std::string input;
    bool expectation;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, Params const & p) {
    return out << "{input=\"" << p.input << "\", expectation=" << p.expectation << "}" << std::endl;
}

class MyClassTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<Params>
{};

TEST_P(MyClassTest, TestAllValues)
{
    MyClass sut;
    EXPECT_EQ(sut.MyFunction(GetParam().input).has_value(), GetParam().expectation);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(OKValues,
                         MyClassTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            Params{"1", true},
                            Params{"1", true},
                            Params{"1", true}
                         ));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(OutOfBound,
                         MyClassTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            Params{"30", true},
                            Params{"40", true},
                            Params{"50", true}
                         ));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Invalid,
                         MyClassTest,
                         testing::Values(
                            Params{"3.0", false},
                            Params{"Foo", false},
                            Params{"Bar", false}
                         ));
```

Note that your example lacked any output that could be tested against, e.g. some return value of `MyClass::MyFunction()`. Thus I added a very simple one. But depending on the way the real code returns the output (exceptions?), different code to check the expectation would be necessary. In principle you could introduce branches in `TEST_P` that check what the expectation should be (e.g. a value or an exception) and then do something differently (e.g. `EXPECT_EQ` vs `EXPECT_THROW`), but this might become confusing if there are multiple such cases. You might be better of with your original way of having one test suite per result "class".